# List problem with extracting data from Twitter XML page

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

With my function I can extract usernames from a twitter xml search page for a friend finder app I am building as a project. The problem though is that when I grab the usernames and input them into a list something strange happens. Instead of having each username as a separate element within a list I have each username being its own list.

So I instead get 20 or so lists. Here is an example of what my code produces
list = ["twitter.com/username"], ["twitter.com/username1"],["twitter.com/username2"]

So you see every single username is its own list. Instead of having one list with three values I have three lists with one value each in them. This is an absolute nightmare to iterate through. How can I make it so I have one list with three elements?

Code is here:

```
def get_names(search_term = raw_input("What term do you want to search for?")):
    search_page = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q="
    search_page += search_term
    data = []
    doc = urllib.urlopen(search_page).read()
    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(''.join(doc))
    data = soup.findAll("uri")
    for uri in soup.findAll('uri'):
        data = []
        uri = str(uri.extract())
        data.append(uri[5:-6] 
        print data
```

Comment: You should try using lxml as it's much faster than BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a new list, called data, for each URI. If you move the `data = []` line out of the `for uri in soup.findAll('uri'):` loop, you should end up with one list instead of a list of lists.

In addition, you've got some other problems. 
There is a syntax error on your next to last line: you're missing a close-parenthesis at the end of the line. 
You've got duplicate lines. Try removing the first `data = []` line, as well as the `data = soup.findAll('url')` line, as you're just doing findAll again for the for loop. 
In addition, you shouldn't put `raw_input` in the function signature, because that means it gets call when you define the function, not when you call the function.

Try this:

```
def get_names():
    search_page = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q="
    search_page += raw_input("What term do you want to search for?")
    doc = urllib.urlopen(search_page).read()
    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(doc)
    doc.close()
    data = [str(uri.extract())[5:-6] for uri in soup.findall('uri')]
    return data
names = get_names()
print(names)
```

Edit: You also don't need to `''.join(doc)`, `read()` returns a single string, not a sequence; `data` can be assembled with a string comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're sort of all over the place in your assignments to data;
I'd suggest changing that code to:

```
def get_names(search_term = raw_input("What term do you want to search for?")):
    search_page = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q="
    search_page += search_term
    data = []
    doc = urllib.urlopen(search_page).read()
    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(''.join(doc))
    for uri in soup.findAll('uri'):
        uri = str(uri.extract())
        data.append(uri[5:-6])
    print data
    return data
```

(untested since I don't know what BeautifulStoneSoup is refering to)

HTH

Pacific

Comment: Not going to work as expected if the function is called more than once because of `raw_input` being run only at function definition time.